# Call Function from another page in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am trying to call a function from another page but its not working. My approach is when i press the button the function called from Message.js should return log to my browser . here's  my code so far

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import {message} from "./Message"

class App extends Component{

 onPress = ()=>{
  this.setState({FromStr: this.state.From})
  this.setState({ToStr: this.state.To})
  this.message
 }

  render(){
return (
  <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
  <Button
      title={"Press"}
      color="#FFFFFF"
      onPress={this.onPress}
  ></Button>
 </View> 
);
}
}

export default App

Message.js:

    export function message() {
   console.log("Hiii")
}
```

Comment: Change this.message to message();

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this.message to message();

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import {message} from "./Message"

class App extends Component{

 onPress = ()=>{
  this.setState({FromStr: this.state.From})
  this.setState({ToStr: this.state.To})
  message();
 }

 render(){
  return (
   <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
     <Button
       title={"Press"}
       color="#FFFFFF"
       onPress={this.onPress}
     />
   </View> 
  );
 }
}
```